# How can I call for transporters earlier?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model that generates a total of 5 loads, each load generated every 2 seconds. When the 5 loads are waiting to be transported, only 1 transporter is called. The transporter fleet has 9 vehicles here.

[image]

I have tried to use a seize transporter block before the convey block, but that only results in 5 transporters queuing at the conveyor for the loads to be generated and picked up.

How can I call a transporter for each of the loads? (In the solution, 5 transporters should be called when they enter the conveyor) Thanks for your help in advance, I am stuck.

**EDIT 1**

I tried out a suggested approach, but my method only generates new transporters with the agent name "Car". How can I call Cars from the existing transporter fleet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As usual, many ways :-)

One could be to create a separate flowchart for your transporters. When a package enters the top conveyor, it can trigger 1 transporter to MoveTo the end of the conveyor location. For that, add a MoveTo block into the new, separate transporter flowchart.

This will make transporters waiting at the conveyor exit, ready to pick up stuff.

Be careful, though, to only summon transporters that are idle anyway.

cheers

Comment: thanks for your response! I have tried working on your suggestion and have used the enter and exit blocks in a separate flowchart, which is triggered by a position on conveyor. However, I am only able to generate "new" transporters. How can I take vehicles from the existing fleet instead?